# Array operation in R

Tags: r

I have a simple question about R.

Suppose I have an array x whose length is a multiple of an integer number h. I would like to construct a new array of length length(x)/h, and whose elements are the sums of the first h elements, then the sum of the next h elements, etc.

I can do it using bad C related coding, but I would like to see the most efficient way to do it with R.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Say your values are

```
x = 1:100
h = 10
```

You could do this by creating a matrix with h rows, and taking the column sums:

```
colSums(matrix(x, nrow=h))
# [1]  55 155 255 355 455 555 655 755 855 955
```

This works because matrix fills in values by column:

```
matrix(x, nrow=h)
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
 [1,]    1   11   21   31   41   51   61   71   81    91
 [2,]    2   12   22   32   42   52   62   72   82    92
 [3,]    3   13   23   33   43   53   63   73   83    93
 [4,]    4   14   24   34   44   54   64   74   84    94
 [5,]    5   15   25   35   45   55   65   75   85    95
 [6,]    6   16   26   36   46   56   66   76   86    96
 [7,]    7   17   27   37   47   57   67   77   87    97
 [8,]    8   18   28   38   48   58   68   78   88    98
 [9,]    9   19   29   39   49   59   69   79   89    99
[10,]   10   20   30   40   50   60   70   80   90   100
```

Comment: Just a side not for future readers, a matrix can be told to fill in values by rows, too.

Answer (score 0):

Or the hard way,

```
y <- unlist(sapply(0:((length(x)/h)-1) , function(k) sum(x[((k)*h + 1):((k+1)*h)] ) ) )
```